# Warning "Range choice direction does not determine aggregate index range direction" when compiling VHDL with QuestaSim

Tags: vhdl, questasim

I am getting a warning which I do not understand when compiling VHDL in QuestaSim:

**(vcom-1514) Range choice direction (downto) does not determine aggregate index range direction (to).**

The code which triggers the warning is similar to having

```
signal foo : unsigned(4 downto 0);
```

in the architecture before the `begin` and then inside some process

```
if foo = (foo'high => '1', foo'high - 1 downto foo'low => '0') then
```

The line above will trigger the warning while

```
if foo = (foo'high => '1', foo'low to foo'high - 1 => '0') then
```

does not, even though the index direction of `foo` is `downto` and not `to`.

Does anyone have an idea why I am supposed to do the indexing with `to` and not with `downto` in this case?

Comment: The same warning is issued when using the `'range` attribute on a `downto`vector (such as `if foo = (foo'range => '1') then`). Similarly to the original question, `reverse_range` does not trigger the warning on a `downto` vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aggregate

```
(foo'high => '1', foo'high - 1 downto foo'low => '0')
```

has the index range direction 'to'. Your warning is saying: *don't imagine its direction is 'downto' just because you've included an array within in which is defined as 'downto'*.

Why is the default direction 'to'? Well, we need to think about what type this aggregate is. (Come on - this is VHDL - it must have a type).

In my code, it's type is `unsigned`. Why? Well, because I have associated it with an input to the procedure of type `unsigned`. In your code its type is also `unsigned`. Why? Well, because it is the right hand argument of the `=` operator, whose left hand argument is definitely `unsigned`. There is only one possible version of the `=` operator that it could be, the one which tests two `unsigned`s.

Now, we need to look at how the type `unsigned` is declared and when we do we see that it is declared as an unconstrained array with an index type of `natural`:

```
type unsigned is array (natural range <>) of std_logic;
```

The left hand value of type `natural` is 0. So, this is why your aggregate has the index range direction 'to'.

---

If you execute this code, you can see how VHDL has defined the indexing on the aggregate:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity E is
end entity ;

architecture A of E is
  signal foo : unsigned(4 downto 0);
begin

  process
    procedure display (constant foo : in unsigned) is
    begin
      report "foo'left= " & integer'image(foo'left);
      report "foo'right= " & integer'image(foo'right);
      report "foo'high= " & integer'image(foo'high);
      report "foo'low= " & integer'image(foo'low);
     end procedure;
  begin
    display((foo'high => '1', foo'high - 1 downto foo'low => '0'));
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture A;
```

Comment: The rules for determining the index range of an aggregate are found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates. Also see 9.3.5 Qualified expressions "A qualified expression is a basic operation (see 5.1) that is used to explicitly state the type, and possibly the subtype, of an operand that is an expression or an aggregate." Where `subtype foo_st is unsigned (4 downto 0);` and for `display(foo_st'(foo'high => '1', foo'high - 1 downto foo'low => '0'));` the aggregate will have an index range 4 downto 0.